# Different results from Solve depending upon the solution variables listed

Tags: equation-solving

Here is a very simple set of equations to solve:

```
Solve[{x == 2,
       y == 0.5,
       z == 0.0,
       r == 0.4,
       dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
       1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)},
      {dbtot, dib}]
```

{{dbtot -> 2.06155, dib -> -0.178513}}

This is the correct answer.

However, if I merely need `dib` and list it as the solution variable...

```
Solve[{x == 2, 
       y == 0.5, 
       z == 0.0, 
       r == 0.4, 
       dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
       1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)} , {dib}]
```

{{dib -> -0.217687}, {dib -> -0.178513}}

This contains the correct solution (`dib -> -0.178513`) as well as an incorrect answer (based on an impossible negative value of `dbtot`).

I've tried `Assuming` and `With` and incorporating constraints such as `dbtot > 0`.  All are (I think) unnecessary and none of them work.

How do I use `Solve` to get the single correct value for `dib`?

An even more elementary illustration of the problem is here:

```
Solve[{r == .4,
       1/dib == -2/r - 1/(2.12132 - r)},
{dib}]
```

{}

What could be simpler than *that*?!

Comment: It is weird at first blush. I think I am missing something here. Anyway, you can ask `Solve` to explicitly eliminate `dbtot` from the system of equations, and then it will return your expected result: `Solve[eq, dib, {dbtot}]`, where `eq` is your system of equations, returns `{{dib -> -0.178513}}`.

Comment: @MarcoB  Thanks, but I'd really like to understand why the straightforward approach simply does not work for a set of very elementary equations and variable assignments.  There should be no need to be smart about eliminating variables in such a situation.

Comment: Replacing `Solve` with `Reduce` handles both your cases. I haven't the foggiest as to why `Solve` is struggling.

Comment: @JackLaVigne  Thanks... that is a help, but still a bit unsatisfactory.  After all, I would like to extract the value of `dib` using `dib /. Reduce[...]` but that will not work elegantly.

Comment: Use `ToRules` with `Reduce` to get rules rather than equations as results.

Comment: Simpler `Solve[{x == 1, dbtot == Sqrt[x^2], dib == dbtot}, {dib}]`

Answer (score 5):

`Solve` seems to work better if you separate definitions from equations.

```
Off[Solve::ratnz]

With[{r = .4, dbtot = 2.06155},
 Solve[1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r), dib]]

(*  {{dib -> -0.178513}}  *)
```

In this next example one of the definitions (`=` vice `==`) is embedded in the `Solve` since it cannot be included with the other definitions since it depends on them.

```
With[{x = 2, y = 0.5, z = 0.0, r = 0.4},
 Solve[dbtot = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]; 
  1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r), dib]]

(*  {{dib -> -0.178513}}  *)
```

Or it can be pulled out

```
With[{x = 2, y = 0.5, z = 0.0, r = 0.4},
 dbtot = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
 Solve[1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r), dib]]

(*  {{dib -> -0.178513}}  *)


Clear[dbtot]

With[{x = 2, y = 0.5, z = 0.0, r = 0.4},
 Solve[{dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
   1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)}, {dbtot, dib}]]

(*  {{dbtot -> 2.06155, dib -> -0.178513}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

From

```
Eliminate[{
    x == 2, y == 0.5, z == 0.0, r == 0.4, 
    dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
    1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)}, 
{dbtot}]
(* 4170. dib + 10525. dib^2 == -409. && 5. r == 2. && x == 2. && 2. y == 1. && z == 0. *)
```

I see that Solve[] (incorrectly) believes `dib` satisfies a quadratic.  This is incorrect squaring of the dib equation after replacement of `dbtot` with `Sqrt[...]`.

`Reduce[]`, however, does not make this error.

```
Reduce[{x == 2, y == 0.5, z == 0.0, r == 0.4, 
    dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
    1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)}, 
{dib}]
(* z == 0 && y == 0.5 && x == 2. && r == 0.4 && dbtot == 2.06155 && dib == -0.178513 &*)

Reduce[{x == 2, y == 0.5, z == 0.0, r == 0.4, 
    dbtot == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
    1/dib == -2/r - 1/(dbtot - r)}, 
{dbtot}]
(* z == 0 && y == 0.5 && x == 2. && r == 0.4 && dib == -0.178513 && dbtot == 2.06155 *)
```

We also get a message, `Reduce::ratnz:` suggesting how `Solve[]` confused itself: it replaced the system with a symbolic representation and picked up a spurious root doing so.